# How to draw a dotted "L" shapped line, When accordion is open?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```js
import BaseAccordian from "@/components/BaseAccordion";

export default {
  components: {
    BaseAccordian,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      accordions: [
        {
          title: "Vue",
          text: "AllaboutVue",
          textwo: "hi",
        },
        {
          title: "Nuxt",
          text: "AllaboutNuxt",
          textwo: "hi",
        },
        {
          title: "webpack",
          text: "Allaboutwebpack",
          textwo: "hi",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.pink {
  color: pink;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div
      v-for="accordion in accordions"
      :key="accordion.title"
      :class="{
        green: accordion.text === 'AllaboutVue',
        red: accordion.textwo === 'hi',
        red: accordion.text === 'AllaboutNuxt',
        pink: accordion.text === 'Allaboutwebpack',
      }"
    >
      <BaseAccordian>
        <template v-slot:title>{{ accordion.title }}</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <div>{{ accordion.text }}</div>
          <div>{{ accordion.textwo }}</div>
        </template>
      </BaseAccordian>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have already set the colours for different text, when the accordion is open , Now I need   draw dotted lines with content on it. So that it draw dotted line based on content colour.

I am thinking that it is possible with css.

I have already set the colours for different text, when the accordion is open , Now I need   draw dotted lines with content on it. So that it draw dotted line based on content colour.

I am thinking that it is possible with css.

Comment: Why would you do that? Can the effect you desire be archived anyhow else?

Comment: your sniped code has errors ...

Comment: @Sundar, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-accordion-component-forked-pny6f?file=/src/components/Accordion.vue)?

Comment: @Sundar, maybe like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-accordion-component-forked-pny6f?file=/src/components/Accordion.vue)? 
It is difficult to understand from the text description what exactly is needed. Try in any graphics editor to draw what you want on the screenshot of this layout.

Comment: @Sundar, watch now https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-accordion-component-forked-pny6f?file=/src/components/Accordion.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240486/discussion-between-7-zete-7-and-sundar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get layout like:

[image]

Just add to your:

```
<div
  v-for="accordion in accordions"
  :key="accordion.title"
  :class="{
    green: accordion.text === 'AllaboutVue',
    red: accordion.textwo === 'hi',
    red: accordion.text === 'AllaboutNuxt',
    pink: accordion.text === 'Allaboutwebpack',
  }"
>
```

class, for example, `line`:

```
<div
  v-for="accordion in accordions"
  :key="accordion.title"
  class="line"
  :class="{
    green: accordion.text === 'AllaboutVue',
    red: accordion.textwo === 'hi',
    red: accordion.text === 'AllaboutNuxt',
    pink: accordion.text === 'Allaboutwebpack',
  }"
>
```

Then add some styles:

```css
.line >>> .content > div {
  --line-width: 2px;
  --x-offset: 8px;
  --x-width: 120px;

  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: var(--line-width);
}
.line >>> .content > div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: var(--x-offset);
  width: var(--x-width);
  height: 100%;
  border-left: var(--line-width) dashed currentColor;
  border-bottom: var(--line-width) dashed currentColor;
}
.line >>> .content > div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--line-width) * 1.75);
  left: calc(var(--x-offset) + var(--x-width));
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: calc(var(--line-width) * 2.5) solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: calc(var(--line-width) * 5) solid currentColor;
}
```